# jquery selector to count the number of visible table rows?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got this html:

```
<table>
    <tr style="display:table-row"><td>blah</td></tr>
    <tr style="display:none"><td>blah</td></tr>
    <tr style="display:none"><td>blah</td></tr>
    <tr style="display:table-row"><td>blah</td></tr>
    <tr style="display:table-row"><td>blah</td></tr>
</table>
```

I need to count the number of rows that *don't* have `display:none`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can use the [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) like this:

```
var numOfVisibleRows = $('tr:visible').length;
```

If the `<table>` itself isn't visible on the screen ([`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) returns false if any parent is hidden, the element doesn't have to be hidden directly), then use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), like this:

```
var numOfVisibleRows = $('tr').filter(function() {
  return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';
}).length;
```

Comment: And if you only want the count to include visible rows in the table-body then use $('tr:visible').length - $('thead>tr').

Answer (score 16):

`$('tr:visible').length`

Answer (score 9):

You can also view particular table visible rows

```
 var totalRow =  $('#tableID tr:visible').length;
 var totalRowWithoutHeader = totalRow-1;
```

The **totalRowWithoutHeader** gives the total row count excluding header row.

Comment: Better not to hard-code the number of header rows and use $('thead>tr').length instead.

Comment: Thanks, that exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

$("tr:visible") gets you the results of the visible rows, and I think you can then do .length

Comment: Not sure why this is upvoted, `.is(":visible")` returns a **boolean**, you cannot call `.length`, instead of `.is()` you'd need `.filter()`.