# jQuery: How to count the number of elements which "display" isn't "none"?

Tags: jquery

I use `show()` and `hide()` to show and hide rows in a table.

How could I count the number of non-hidden rows (more accurately, rows with `display` != `none`) ?

Note that:

```
$('tr:visible').length
```

won't work because if the table itself has `display=none`, the result will always be 0.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Filter your rows based on their actual CSS property:

```
$('tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';
}).length;
```

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
$('tr:not([style*="display: none"])').length
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/7LvD5/

Comment: should work in most cases, but could break because it is just a substring match, and not an exact equality test.

Comment: True, but he said he was using hide() and it works with that.

Comment: Yes, but what happens if some other property 'foo-display: none' is set?  Your substring match would (incorrectly) detect that.

Comment: Good point. Your way definitely seems like the better way to do it.

Comment: I found this the better solution for matching against class and feel it unlikely the foo-display point would surface in many scenarios...  none really come to mind.

Answer (score 2):

[jquery selector to count the number of visible table rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931893/jquery-selector-to-count-the-number-of-visible-table-rows)

Change !== to ===

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to the mix. I found this to be a more reliable option.

```
function recount () {
    var numOfVisibleRows = jQuery('tr.itemtext:visible').length;
    document.getElementById("item_table_count").innerHTML = numOfVisibleRows;
}
```

I like this because my table *itemtext* is hiding rows in different ways. I hope it's useful.

See this question for more information: [jquery selector to count the number of visible table rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931893/jquery-selector-to-count-the-number-of-visible-table-rows)