# How to determine if a table row is visible or not?

Tags: jquery

I want to know how to identify table row is visible or not. I want to resolve by using jQuery

Comment: Possibly related *[jquery selector to count the number of visible table rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931893/jquery-selector-to-count-the-number-of-visible-table-rows)*

Comment: A very cryptic question to start with. You need to be a bit generous while giving out information about your problem, the context and what you have tried so far. You are welcome to share your code as weel. These efforts from your side will help others willing to provide you some answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) pseudo-selector, and the [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method, which returns a boolean value:

```
if($("#tableRowId").is(":visible")) {
    //It's visible
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is visible should help you :-

```
$('#table_row').is(':visible')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var none=$("table tr").css("display")

if(none=="none"){
// Row is invisible
} else{
// Row is visible
}
```

Comment: it should be `none=="none"` and not `=` because that way, you're assigning it to the variable.