# jQuery - Count number/Get Index of rowspan rows

Tags: jquery, count, html-table

I'm trying to figure out how to get the index of the current rowspanned "row" (even though its the cell that is rowspanned).

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">First</td>
        <td> First 1 1 </td>
        <td> First 2 1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td> First 2 1 </td>
         <td> First 2 2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Second</td>
        <td> Second 1 1 </td>
        <td> Second 2 1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td> Second 2 1 </td>
         <td> Second 2 2 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If I clicked on any cell in the table, how can I count which "row-spanned" row I'm at?

For example if I click on any of the "Second" cells, I should get "2" and if I click on any of the "First" cells, I should get "1".

I've tried multiple things include this:

```
row=$(this).parent().parent().children('tr').filter(function (index) {
    return $(this).children('td[rowspan]'); }).index($(this).parent());
```

and

```
row=$(this).parent().parent().children('tr:contains("td[rowspan]")')
    .parent().parent().index($(this).parent());
```

and sort-of got it to work with

```
$row=$(this).parent();
while ($row.children('td:eq(0)').attr("rowspan").length<=0)
    $row=$row.prev();
span=$row.children('td:eq(0)').attr("rowspan");
row=Math.floor( parseInt($(this).parent().parent().children().index( $(this).parent()) )/span );
```

but this will only work give that there is a rowspan cell... and is assuming that all rows have that same rowspan

I tried working off these site, but couldn't get too far.

[jquery selector to count the number of visible table rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931893/jquery-selector-to-count-the-number-of-visible-table-rows)

[JQuery: How to select rows from a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585272/jquery-how-to-select-rows-from-a-table)

[Table row and column number in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788225/table-row-and-column-number-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to build an array from the `rowspan` attributes of the cells in the first column. From there, you can get the index of the clicked row and iterate over the `rowspan` array, subtracting the extents of the spans as you go. Once you go below zero, you have your (zero-based) index:

```
$("td").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var rowIndex = $this.closest("tr").index();
    $this.closest("table").find("tr").map(function() {
        return $(this).find("td:first").attr("rowspan") || 1;
    }).each(function(index) {
        if ((rowIndex -= this) < 0) {
            alert(index + 1);  // 'index' is zero-based.
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

You can test it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tEC7/2/).

Comment: One problem I ran into on the fiddle was if I removed the rowspan from the first row and just had two rows of three cells, the "Second" cells didn't respond on click for some reason... is that just me?

Comment: @jao, you're right, I was not properly taking the "no rowspan" case into account. This is now fixed.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I'm getting "3" when I click on the Second 2 1 and Second 2 2.

Answer (score 3):

```
var table = $('table');                     // reference of table
$('td').click(function() {
  var perent = $(this).parent();            // find parent tr
      index= table.find(perent).index();    // get index of tr
   alert( index );
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NTAmE/4/)**

```
var table = $('table');
$('td').click(function() {
    var tdWithRowSpan = $(this).siblings('td[rowspan]').length ?  // if siblings td[rowspan] exists
                            $(this).siblings('td[rowspan]') :     // get that td
                              $(this).parent().prev('tr').find('td[rowspan]'); // else find closest td[rowspan]


    index = table.find('td[rowspan]').index(tdWithRowSpan); // get index
    alert(index);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NTAmE/6/)**

Comment: @jao check my answer and demo, I think it will resolve your problem without changing current `HTML`

Comment: That gives me 0->1st row, 1->2nd row, 2-> 3rd row, 3->4th row. I need 1->1st row, 1->2nd row, 2-> 3rd row, 2->4th row. I guess I could divide the row number by 2 and Math.floor it.

Comment: if you have more than 2 rowspan is it alright to put in a "while not rowspan go prev()?" or will that be bad since it will crash if no rowspan exists?

Comment: @jao no it will not crash, just give index `-1`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you want; but consider adding data attributes to your markup to make your life easier...

```
<table>
    <tr data-index="0">
        <td rowspan="2">First</td>
        <td> First 1 1 </td>
        <td> First 2 1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="1">
         <td> First 2 1 </td>
         <td> First 2 2 </td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

With this in place, getting the value is trivial:

```
$(this).parent().attr("data-index");
```

Comment: i know with HTML5 that is "legal", but is that considered good practice? I would definitely make my life easier

Comment: @jao sure, it's fine as far as I know.  Older browsers can still retrieve custom attributes.  According to this guy, it even works in IE6:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6